# Abstract is shown in other language

Tags: languages, overleaf, abstract

I am new to Overleaf (Latex as well) and I am using the template [HW template for Machine Learning 1 - UvA](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/hw-template-for-machine-learning-1-uva/zsdcvnmbzzyh).

When I used the command `\begin{abstract}` and recompile the file, the word `Zusammenfassung` appears in stead of `Abstract` in the document.
Here are the screen shots,

Code:

[image: Code]

Output:

[image: Output]

May I know how to make the `Zusammenfassung` back into English? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `head.tex` file, change the line

```
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel} % Language hyphenation and typographical rules
```

into

```
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Language hyphenation and typographical rules
```

Then recompile, you get the word **Abstract** in English.

[image]

Comment: A little addition to @hesham's answer: If you want to use ngerman babel with english babel, change order of declaration such as `\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel} `.